# jQuery: hide and show for div's

Tags: jquery

i want to show the div for 3 sec. and show the next div for 3 sec. and continue this timer.
but this code is not working if there is an other code to solve this problem.

```
var timer = setInterval(showDiv(3000));
var counter = 0;

function showDiv() {
  if (counter ==0) 
    counter++;
  $('#text1, #text2').stop().hide().filter(function() { 
    return this.id.match('#text' + counter); 
  }).show();
  counter == 2? counter = 0 : counter++; 
}
showDiv();

});
```

Comment: it should be `setInterval(showDiv, 3000);`

Comment: I think you could use jQuery animate, wich is more suited.

Answer (score 0):

The filter function should return a boolean value if an element matches or not. Here this.id.match returns an array which is the result of regular expression execution. Instead of using a function for filter, you can simplify it like this:

```
  setInterval(showDiv,3000);
  var counter = 0;
  function showDiv() {
    if (counter ==0) { counter++;}
    $('#text1, #text2')
      .stop()
      .hide()
      .filter('#text'+counter)   
      .show();
    counter == 2? counter = 0 : counter++; 
  }
```